# How to show names in a Lync 2013 conversation with more than 1 person?

Tags: lync-2013

- If I have a Lync conversation with 1 person  I see their name in the tab as well as in the header of the conversation next to their picture.
- If I have a conversation with **more than one other person** Lync shows *Conversation (x participants)* in the tab and the header shows just the pictures/photos of the other participants.

**My question is:** Is there a way to get the names to show instead of, or in addition to the pictures on the conversation header with more than 1 person?

The trouble is that most of the people in our organization have not provided a picture yet so  I see the default blank profile of a person picture, but I can't tell who is in the conversation without hovering over each blank photo to get the tooltip.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem today, no one has pictures uploaded at our company.

In the lower left are the icons for Conversation, Call, Video, Sharing Monitors and then Participant List. Clicking the Participant List replaces the picture icons with a scrollable list of names.

[image: Lync showing participant list]